# How can i use JQuery for an image tag

Tags: jquery

I have an image tag inside a div.  I am trying to use JQuery and get the image tag as a button and get a drop down menu when you click on it.  Any adivse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Register a click listener on the image that will show the dropdown:

```
$("#imgId").click(function(){
   $("#dropdownId").show();
});
```

Comment: The problem now is the dropdown menu goes down ok but its goes back up the page.  I just want it to drop down and stay there, any advise?

Comment: What do you mean back up the page? It's difficult to help you if you don't show your code. Ideally post a jsfiddle of it.

Comment: <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideDown("slow");
 
  });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
 
<div class="maincol2">
 
 
<img class = "flip"  height="150" width="200" src = "images/images/computer1.jpg" alt="Computer Support"/>

<div class = "panel"><p>DropDown Menu</p>



</div>

</div>

</body>

Comment: Please put it in your question and format it using the code tags.